# Python web scaping recursively (next page)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lxml

from this website:
https://search2.ucl.ac.uk/s/search.html?query=max&collection=website-meta&profile=_directory&tab=directory&f.Profile+Type%7Cg=Student&start_rank=1

I need to scrape the next pages 2, 3 ...using Selenium or LXML.
I can only scrape the first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
nextNumberIsThere = True
i=1
while nextNumberIsThere:
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollHeight");
    profileDetails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='profile-details']/li")
    for element in profileDetails:
        print(element.text)
    next = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='"+str(i)+"']")
    i+=1
    if len(next) > 0:
        next[0].click()
    else:
        nextNumberIsThere = False
```

The above code will iterate and fetch the data until there are no numbers left.

If you want to fetch the name, department, email separately then try the below code :

```
nextNumberIsThere = True
i=1
while nextNumberIsThere:
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollHeight");
    profileDetails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='profile-details']")
    for element in profileDetails:
        name = element.find_element_by_xpath("./li[@class='fn']")
        department = element.find_elements_by_xpath("./li[@class='org']")
        email = element.find_element_by_xpath("./li[@class='email']")
        print(name.text)
        print(department.text)
        print(email.text)
        print("------------------------------")
        next = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='"+str(i)+"']")
    i+=1
    if len(next) > 0:
        next[0].click()
    else:
        nextNumberIsThere = False
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Change `start_rank` in the url. For example:

https://search2.ucl.ac.uk/s/search.html?query=max&collection=website-meta&profile=_directory&tab=directory&f.Profile+Type%7Cg=Student&start_rank=11

Comment: yes, I already did it, but I can't know when to stop, I means if the last page is 50 or 40; because  I will create a loop for the number of pages available for each name, I don't know how much page for each name:  for example if we search for 'alex' https://search2.ucl.ac.uk/s/search.html?query=alex&collection=website-meta&profile=_directory&tab=directory&sumbit=Go&f.Profile+Type%7Cg=Student

Comment: I think you can't see more than 50 results for a given query.
If this is the case, you could refine your queries, and use also available sortings,
until your search results are <= 50

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this kind of problem is not to use a loop that iterates through "all the pages" (because you don't know how many there are up-front), but rather have some kind of queue, where scraping one page optionally adds subsequent pages to the queue, to be scraped later.

In your specific example, during the scraping of each page you could look for the link to "next page" and, if it's there, add the next page's URL to the queue, so it will be scraped following the current page; once you hit a page with no "next page" link, the queue will empty and scraping will stop. 
A more complex example might include scraping a category page and adding each of its sub-categories as a subsequent page to the scraping queue, each of which might in turn add multiple item pages to the queue, etc.

Take a look at scraping frameworks like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which include this kind of functionality easily in their design. You might find some of its other features useful as well, e.g. its ability to find elements on the page using either XPath or CSS selectors.

The first example on the Scrapy homepage shows exactly the kind of functionality you're trying to implement:

```py
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('.post-header>h2'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').get()}

        for next_page in response.css('a.next-posts-link'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

One important note about Scrapy: it doesn't use Selenium (at least not out-of-the-box), but rather downloads the page source and parses it. This means that it doesn't run JavaScript, which might be an issue for you if the website you're scraping is client-generated. In that case, you could look into solutions that combine Scrapy and Selenium (quick googling shows a bunch of them, as well as StackOverflow answers regarding this problem), or you could stick to your Selenium scraping code and implement a queuing mechanism yourself, without Scrapy.

Comment: For the website he's scraping this wont work, as `next` button never disappears.
In fact, after the page `5` the `next` simply redirect to the fifth page again, and loop never ends. One option could be to check if results from a page are identical to previous ones, or simply scrape first 5 pages, or 50 results, as I would suggest. 
I'd refine queries and use sortings if I'm interested in gathering as much data as I can